# How to create obstacles in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a simple platformer like game.The code i am using is shown below

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 var rightKeyPress = false;
 var leftKeyPress = false;
 var upKeyPress = false;
 var downKeyPress = false;
 var playerX = canvas.width / 2;
 var playerY = -50;
 var dx = 3;
 var dy = 3;
 var dxp = 3;
 var dyp = 3;
 var dxn = 3;
 var dyn = 3;
 var prevDxp = dxp;
 var prevDyp = dyp;
 var prevDxn = dxn;
 var prevDyn = dyn;
 var playerWidth = 50;
 var playerHeight = 50;
 var obstacleWidth = 150;
 var obstacleHeight = 50;
 var obstaclePadding = 10;
 var G = .98;
 var currentVelocity = 0;
 var obstacles = [];
 var imageLoaded = false;

 document.addEventListener("keyup",keyUp,false);
 document.addEventListener("keydown",keyDown,false);

 function keyDown(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 37){
   leftKeyPress = true;
   if(currentVelocity > 2){
    currentVelocity -= .1;
   }
  }
  if(e.keyCode == 38){
   upKeyPress = true;
  }
  if(e.keyCode == 39){
   rightKeyPress = true;
   if(currentVelocity < 2){
    currentVelocity += .1;
   }
  }
  if(e.keyCode == 40){
   downKeyPress = true;
  }
 }
 function keyUp(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 37){
   leftKeyPress = false;
  }
  if(e.keyCode == 38){
   upKeyPress = false;
  }
  if(e.keyCode == 39){
   rightKeyPress = false;
  }
  if(e.keyCode == 40){
   downKeyPress = false;
  }
 }
 function createObstacles(){
  for(x=0;x < 4;x++){
   var obX = (200 * x) + Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
   var obY = 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 400);
   obstacles.push({"x":obX,"y":obY});
  }
 }
 createObstacles();
 function drawObstacles(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(x=0;x < 4;x++){
   var obX = obstacles[x].x;
   var obY = obstacles[x].y;
   ctx.rect(obX,obY,obstacleWidth,obstacleHeight)
  } 
  ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
 }
 function initPlayer(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(playerX,playerY,50,50);
  ctx.fillStyle="orange";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
 }
 function KeyPressAndGravity(){
  checkObstacleCollision();
  playerX += currentVelocity;
  if(rightKeyPress && playerX + 50 < canvas.width){
   playerX += dxp;
  }
  if(leftKeyPress && playerX > 0){
   playerX -= dxn;
  }
  if(upKeyPress && playerY > 0){
   playerY -= dyn;
  }
  if(downKeyPress && playerY + 50 < canvas.height){
   playerY += dyp;
  }
  if(playerY+50 < canvas.height){
   playerY += G;
  }
  if(playerX <= 0){
   currentVelocity = 0;
  }else if(playerX + 50 >= canvas.width){
   currentVelocity = 0;
  }
  dxp = prevDxp;
  dyp = prevDyp;
  dxn = prevDxn;
  dyn = prevDyn;
  G = .98;
  if(currentVelocity != 0){
   if(currentVelocity > 0){
    currentVelocity -= .01;
   }else{
    currentVelocity += .01;
   }
  }
 }
  /*-----------------------------------------------------------
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  ---------------------------Check this part-------------------
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  ------------------------------------------------------------*/
 function checkObstacleCollision(){
  var obLen = obstacles.length;
  for(var x=0;x<obLen;x++){
   var obX = obstacles[x].x;
   var obY = obstacles[x].y;
   if((playerX + playerWidth > obX && playerX + playerWidth < obX + obstacleWidth || playerX > obX && playerX < obX + obstacleWidth) && playerY + playerHeight > obY - obstaclePadding && playerY + playerHeight < obY){
    dyp = 0;
    G = 0;
   }else if((playerX + playerWidth > obX && playerX + playerWidth < obX + obstacleWidth || playerX > obX && playerX < obX + obstacleWidth) && playerY > obY + obstacleHeight && playerY < obY + obstacleHeight + obstaclePadding){
    dyn = 0;
   }else if(playerX + playerWidth > obX - obstaclePadding && playerX + playerWidth < obX && ((playerY + playerHeight > obY && playerY + playerHeight < obY + obstacleHeight) || (playerY > obY && playerY < obY + obstacleHeight))){
    dxp = 0;
   }else if(playerX  > obX + obstacleWidth && playerX < obX + obstacleWidth + obstaclePadding && ((playerY + playerHeight > obY && playerY + playerHeight < obY + obstacleHeight) || (playerY > obY && playerY < obY +  obstacleHeight))){
    dxn = 0;
   }

  }
 }
 function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  initPlayer();
  KeyPressAndGravity();
  drawObstacles();
 }

 setInterval(draw,15);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="1000" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000;"></canvas>
```

The problem is that sometimes when the speed of the "player" is high it can go through obstacles like the below image. How can i stop that from happening ?

[image]

So what i want is that the player should stop right as he reaches the obstacle and not pass through it

Comment: This is a common problem in game development. You need to calculate where the player will be in the next frame and check if it passed a collider, if yes, make it collide. Also, I wouldn't check the collision for every collider, but only those that are within a given distance, otherwise you might soon have performance issues.

Comment: Yeah i will try it like that thanks @JonasGrumann

Comment: You have over 8K rep on SO and still don't know how to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry if i didn't make it clear @hindmost what more should i add ?

Comment: This is a very broad subject, covering complete books, and you should encounter terms like bounding boxes or bounding circles, broad phase and narrow phase and a bunch of other terms in your search. If you want to find your answer on the Stack Exchange network, maybe a good start is [How does a collision engine work?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26501/how-does-a-collision-engine-work) on GameDev SE.

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol i will surely have a look at that

Comment: I use a game engine called [PhaserJs](http://www.phaser.io/) for my 2d browser based games. Its Source is on github. Whilst others are mentioning good ways to solve the issue looking at the [Physics Engines](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/tree/master/src/physics) available in phaser may help if you wish to roll your own. EDIT: I believe  the Arcade system is core, the others a separate libraries pulled in. But i could be wrong on that.

Comment: @ste2425 Hello thanks for that i am trying it out

Comment: @Akshay Great Stuff. On a completely unrelated side note id take a look at [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) over `setInterval` for your game if possible.

Comment: I will definitely change to `requestAnimationFrame` @ste2425

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is a complication when collision testing objects that are moving quickly**

You must determine if your player and obstacle intersected *at **any time** during the move* -- even if the player has moved beyond the obstacle by the end of the move. Therefore you must account for the complete path the player has moved from start to end of the move.

[image] ... [image]

Then you can check if the player ever intersected the obstacle during the move by checking if the player's track intersects the obstacle.

[image]

**A relatively efficient method for testing collisions involving fast moving objects**

1. Define the 3 line segments that connect the 3 vertices of the player's starting rectangle that are closest to the player's ending rectangle.

[image]

2. For any of the 3 lines that intersect an obstacle, calculate the distance of the line segment to the obstacle. Select the line that has the shortest distance between starting vertex and the obstacle.

[image] [image]

3. Calculate the "x" & "y" distances of the selected line segment.

   ```
   var dx = obstacleIntersection.x - start.x;
   var dy = obstacleIntersection.y - start.y;
   ```
4. Move the player from their starting position by the distance calculated in #3. This results in the player moving to the spot where it first collided with the obstacle.

   ```
   player.x += dx;
   player.y += dy;
   ```

[image]

**Code and Demo:**

Useful functions in the code:

- `setPlayerVertices` determines the 3 line segments that connect the 3 vertices of the player's starting rectangle that are closest to the player's ending rectangle.
- `hasCollided` finds the shortest segment connecting a vertex from the player's starting position with the collision point on the obstacle.
- `line2lineIntersection` finds the intersection point (if any) between 2 lines. This is used to test for an intersection between a start-to-end segment (from #1) and any of the 4 line segments that make up the obstacle rectangle. *Attribution:* This function is adapted from Paul Bourke's useful [treatice on intersections](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/).

[image]

Here is example code and a Demo showing how to halt the player at the collision point on the obstacle:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY,dragging;

ctx.translate(0.50,0.50);
ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';

var pts;
var p1={x:50,y:50,w:25,h:25,fill:''};
var p2={x:250,y:250,w:25,h:25,fill:''};
var ob={x:100,y:150,w:125,h:25,fill:''};
var obVertices=[
    {x:ob.x,y:ob.y},
    {x:ob.x+ob.w,y:ob.y},
    {x:ob.x+ob.w,y:ob.y+ob.h},
    {x:ob.x,y:ob.y+ob.h}
];
var s1,s2,s3,e1,e2,e3,o1,o2,o3,o4;

draw();

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});


function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    //
    ctx.lineWidth=4;
    ctx.globalAlpha=0.250;
    ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
    ctx.strokeRect(ob.x,ob.y,ob.w,ob.h);
    ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
    ctx.fillStyle='black';
    ctx.fillText('obstacle',ob.x+ob.w/2,ob.y+ob.h/2);
    //
    ctx.globalAlpha=0.250;
    ctx.strokeStyle='gold';
    ctx.strokeRect(p1.x,p1.y,p1.w,p1.h);
    ctx.strokeStyle='purple';
    ctx.strokeRect(p2.x,p2.y,p2.w,p2.h);
    ctx.fillStyle='black';
    ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
    ctx.fillText('start',p1.x+p1.w/2,p1.y+p1.h/2);
    ctx.fillText('end',p2.x+p2.w/2,p2.y+p2.h/2);
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  var mx=startX;
  var my=startY;
  if(mx>p1.x && mx<p1.x+p1.w && my>p1.y && my<p1.y+p1.h){
      isDown=true;
      dragging=p1;
  }else if(mx>p2.x && mx<p2.x+p2.w && my>p2.y && my<p2.y+p2.h){
      isDown=true;
      dragging=p2;
  }
}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isDown=false;
  dragging=null;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousemove stuff here
  var dx=mouseX-startX;
  var dy=mouseY-startY;
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;
  //
  dragging.x+=dx;
  dragging.y+=dy;
  //
  draw();
  //
  setPlayerVertices(p1,p2);
  var c=hasCollided(obVertices);
  if(c.dx){
      ctx.strokeStyle='gold';
      ctx.strokeRect(p1.x+c.dx,p1.y+c.dy,p1.w,p1.h);
      ctx.fillStyle='black';
      ctx.fillText('hit',p1.x+c.dx+p1.w/2,p1.y+c.dy+p1.h/2);
      line(c.s,c.i,'red');
  }
}

function setPlayerVertices(p1,p2){
    var tl1={x:p1.x,      y:p1.y};
    var tl2={x:p2.x,      y:p2.y};
    var tr1={x:p1.x+p1.w, y:p1.y};
    var tr2={x:p2.x+p2.w, y:p2.y};
    var br1={x:p1.x+p1.w, y:p1.y+p1.h};
    var br2={x:p2.x+p2.w, y:p2.y+p2.h};
    var bl1={x:p1.x,      y:p1.y+p1.h};
    var bl2={x:p2.x,      y:p2.y+p2.h};
    //
    if(p1.x<=p2.x && p1.y<=p2.y){
        s1=tr1; s2=br1; s3=bl1;
        e1=tr2; e2=br2; e3=bl2;
        o1=0; o2=1; o3=3; o4=0;
    }else if(p1.x<=p2.x && p1.y>=p2.y){
        s1=tl1; s2=tr1; s3=br1;
        e1=tl2; e2=tr2; e3=br2;
        o1=2; o2=3; o3=3; o4=0;
    }else if(p1.x>=p2.x && p1.y<=p2.y){
        s1=tl1; s2=br1; s3=bl1;
        e1=tl2; e2=br2; e3=bl2;
        o1=0; o2=1; o3=1; o4=2;
    }else if(p1.x>=p2.x && p1.y>=p2.y){
        s1=tl1; s2=tr1; s3=bl1;
        e1=tl2; e2=tr2; e3=bl2;
        o1=1; o2=2; o3=2; o4=3;
    }
}

function hasCollided(o){
    //
    var i1=line2lineIntersection(s1,e1,o[o1],o[o2]);
    var i2=line2lineIntersection(s2,e2,o[o1],o[o2]);
    var i3=line2lineIntersection(s3,e3,o[o1],o[o2]);
    var i4=line2lineIntersection(s1,e1,o[o3],o[o4]);
    var i5=line2lineIntersection(s2,e2,o[o3],o[o4]);
    var i6=line2lineIntersection(s3,e3,o[o3],o[o4]);
    //
    var tracks=[];
    if(i1){tracks.push(track(s1,e1,i1));}
    if(i2){tracks.push(track(s2,e2,i2));}
    if(i3){tracks.push(track(s3,e3,i3));}
    if(i4){tracks.push(track(s1,e1,i4));}
    if(i5){tracks.push(track(s2,e2,i5));}
    if(i6){tracks.push(track(s3,e3,i6));}
    //
    var nohitDist=10000000;
    var minDistSq=nohitDist;
    var halt={dx:null,dy:null,};
    for(var i=0;i<tracks.length;i++){
        var t=tracks[i];
        var testdist=t.dx*t.dx+t.dy*t.dy;
        if(testdist<minDistSq){
            minDistSq=testdist;
            halt.dx=t.dx;
            halt.dy=t.dy;
            halt.s=t.s;
            halt.i=t.i;
        }
    }
    return(halt);
}
//
function track(s,e,i){
    dot(s);dot(i);line(s,i);line(i,e);
    return({ dx:i.x-s.x, dy:i.y-s.y, s:s, i:i });
}


function line2lineIntersection(p0,p1,p2,p3) {
    var unknownA = (p3.x-p2.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p3.y-p2.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var unknownB = (p1.x-p0.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p1.y-p0.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var denominator  = (p3.y-p2.y) * (p1.x-p0.x) - (p3.x-p2.x) * (p1.y-p0.y);        
    // Test if Coincident
    // If the denominator and numerator for the ua and ub are 0
    //    then the two lines are coincident.    
    if(unknownA==0 && unknownB==0 && denominator==0){return(null);}
    // Test if Parallel 
    // If the denominator for the equations for ua and ub is 0
    //     then the two lines are parallel. 
    if (denominator == 0) return null;
    // If the intersection of line segments is required 
    // then it is only necessary to test if ua and ub lie between 0 and 1.
    // Whichever one lies within that range then the corresponding
    // line segment contains the intersection point. 
    // If both lie within the range of 0 to 1 then 
    // the intersection point is within both line segments. 
    unknownA /= denominator;
    unknownB /= denominator;
    var isIntersecting=(unknownA>=0 && unknownA<=1 && unknownB>=0 && unknownB<=1)
    if(!isIntersecting){return(null);}
    return({
        x: p0.x + unknownA * (p1.x-p0.x),
        y: p0.y + unknownA * (p1.y-p0.y)
    });
}

function dot(pt){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pt.x,pt.y,3,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function line(p0,p1,stroke,lw){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(p0.x,p0.y);
    ctx.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
    ctx.lineWidth=lw || 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle=stroke || 'gray';
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag start & end player position rects<br>The shortest segment intersecting the obstacle is red.<br>The repositioned player is shown on the obstacle.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: @markE Great answer. I would just make one comment on the way you return values from line intercept and track. Rather than create a new object for every call (a memory allocation and a GC overhead) add the return structure as an optional last argument  eg `function lineIntcept(p1,p2,p3,p4,point){ if(point === undefined){ point = {x:null,y:null};}` then `point.x = //answer x; point.y = //answer.y; return point;` that will save a lot of CPU time per call if point is provided. It is just a trivial point, as the answer is great.

Comment: Thanks :-) Yep, passing the values by reference argument is more efficient -- especially because the collision test is likely called often and with multiple obstacles.

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is usually called tunneling.

There are **lot's** of different ways to solve it, but the easiest is usually to save last position and do one of the following.

**A**

Calculate a new larger collision box for each element, containing the element's last position and it's new one. Think of this as a box containing your element twice. Once for it's last position (LP) and one for it's new position (NP),

```
 ------------
|| LP |      |
||____|      |
|       ____ |
|      | NP ||
|______|____||
```

Now if you use this new box to check collisions, it will take the path travelled into account to avoid tunneling. This might create unexpected collisions in the top right and bottom left corner, but it's a simple implementation and the tradeoff might be worth it.

**B**

Check collisions for each step along the path traveled from it's last position to it's new position. If your element has traveled 5 pixels since the last frame, you check the collision once for each pixel (or minimum acceptable collision distance).

```
 ____
| LP |      
|____||      
  ---- |___ 
   |___|NP |
      |____|
```

This will of course increase the number of collision detections and have an impact on performance. Here you could look into quadtrees to compensate for the performance loss.

Moving forward, there are a lot more elegant and advanced solutions, but the subject is to broad for a complete answer here.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks i am trying it and i have almost manged to make it working

Answer (score 1):

Well, I made a "collision calculator" about several months ago, so you can change and use the code below as you like :) For better explanation:

- p_x is last player position x plus his width
- p_y is last player position y plus his height
- p_x_m is last player position x
- p_y_m is last player position y
- y_m is new player position (his y - somevalue)
- x_m is new player position (his x - somevalue)
- y_p is new player position (his y + somevalue + his height)
- y_p_m is new player position (his y + somevalue)
- x_p is new player position (his x + somevalue + his width)
- x_p_m is new player position (his x + somevalue)
- w_x is wall position x
- w_y is wall position y
- w_w is wall width
- w_h is wall height
- pressedKeys is a string telling which keys player pressed (for example "was" or "wd" or "ad" etc.)
- `this.walls` is a variable with walls (for example if I've got 4 walls the array would look like `[false,'s',false,false]` because I touched second wall with "s" key).

---

Code:

```
if(
    pressedKeys.indexOf("s")>-1 &&
    (
        (                                                                                   //      P
            p_y>w_y&&p_y<(w_y+w_h)&&x_p_m>w_x && x_p-5>w_x && x_m<w_x                       //      +----
        ) ||                                                                                //      |

        (                                                                                   //      P
            y_p>w_y&&p_y<(w_y+w_h) && x_p-5>w_x && x_p<=(w_x+w_w)                           //  +--------+
        ) ||                                                                                //  |        |

        (                                                                                   //      P
            y_p>w_y&&p_y<(w_y+w_h) && x_p>(w_x+w_w)&&p_x_m<(w_x+w_w) && x_m+5<(w_x+w_w)     //  ----+
        )                                                                                   //      |
    )
)
{
    if(this.walls[i] == false)
        this.walls[i] = "";
    this.walls[i] += "s";
}
if(
    pressedKeys.indexOf("d")>-1 &&
    (
        (                                                                                   //      P+----
            p_x>w_x&&p_x<(w_x+w_w)&&y_p_m>w_y && y_p-5>w_y && y_m<w_y                       //       |
        ) ||                                                                                //       |

        (                                                                                   //       |
            x_p>w_x&&p_x<(w_x+w_w) && y_p-5>w_y && y_p<=(w_y+w_h)                           //      P|
        ) ||                                                                                //       |

        (                                                                                   //       |
            x_p>w_x&&p_x<(w_x+w_w) && y_p>(w_y+w_h)&&p_y_m<(w_y+w_h) && y_m+5<(w_y+w_h)     //       |
        )                                                                                   //      P+----
    )
)
{
    if(this.walls[i] == false)
        this.walls[i] = "";
    this.walls[i] += "d";
}
if(
    pressedKeys.indexOf("w")>-1 &&
    (
        (                                                                                   //      |
            y_m<(w_y+w_h)&&y_p-5>w_y && x_p-5>w_x && x_m<w_x &&x_p_m>w_x                    //      +----
        ) ||                                                                                //      P

        (                                                                                   //  |        |
            y_m<(w_y+w_h)&&y_p-5>w_y && x_p-5>w_x && x_p<=(w_x+w_w)                         //  +--------+
        ) ||                                                                                //      P    

        (                                                                                   //      |
            y_m<(w_y+w_h)&&y_p-5>w_y && x_p>(w_x+w_w)&&p_x_m<(w_x+w_w) && x_m+5<(w_x+w_w)   //  ----+
        )                                                                                   //      P
    )
)
{
    if(this.walls[i] == false)
        this.walls[i] = "";
    this.walls[i] += "w";
}
if(
    pressedKeys.indexOf("a")>-1 &&
    (
        (                                                                                   //  ----+P
            x_m<(w_x+w_w)&&x_p-5>w_x && y_p-5>w_y && y_m<w_y &&y_p_m>w_y                    //      |
        ) ||                                                                                //      |

        (                                                                                   //      |
            x_m<(w_x+w_w)&&x_p-5>w_x && y_p-5>w_y && y_p<=(w_y+w_h)                         //      |P
        ) ||                                                                                //      |    

        (                                                                                   //      |
            x_m<(w_x+w_w)&&x_p-5>w_x && y_p>(w_y+w_h)&&p_y_m<(w_y+w_h) && y_m+5<(w_y+w_h)   //      |P
        )                                                                                   //  ----+P
    )
)
{
    if(this.walls[i] == false)
        this.walls[i] = "";
    this.walls[i] += "a";
}
```

Comments at the right side of the code show how player collides.

This code 100% works, I use it everytime I want to check for collision.

Hope it helped a bit :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, nice code you have (a bit complex) i will try it out