# Find which side of rectangle collided after testCollision function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-physics

I currently have two objects bulletList and enemyList each containing properties of their X and Y position on canvas. What I want to program is to find which side the bullet collides the enemies. The if statement runs after the testCollision function

So far I've created this:

```
if(bulletLocationY < enemyLocationY)

    console.log("Above");

if(bulletLocationY > enemyLocationY)

    console.log("Below");


if(bulletLocationX < enemyLocationX)
    console.log("Left");


if(bulletLocationX > enemyLocationX)
  console.log("Right");
```

Current example of the game: https://jsfiddle.net/pktxmc3y/

Effectively what I want to do is when the bullet hits the red enemy on the left side, the enemy moves rightwards and vice-versa. When I hit the enemy from above it moves downwards and vice-versa. The bit I found difficult is identifying the side where the bullet hit the rectangle.

EDIT: Just to add to the correct answer I've also had success using:

```
if(bulletLocationY - (bulletHeight/2) < enemyLocationY  - (enemyHeight/2))

    console.log("Above");

if(bulletLocationY + (bulletHeight/2) > enemyLocationY + (enemyHeight/2))

    console.log("Below");


if(bulletLocationX - (bulletWidth/2)< enemyLocationX - (enemyWidth/2))
    console.log("Left");


if(bulletLocationX + (bulletWidth/2)> enemyLocationX + (enemyWidth/2))
  console.log("Right");
```

Comment: Given 2 rectangles, [this previous Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607871/how-to-create-obstacles-in-canvas/34624007#34624007) shows how to calculate the initial collision point (if any) of the 2 rectangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't know from where the bullet hit just from its current position. Now the bullet is inside the enemy, and for instance if its in the upper left, it might just as well come from the left or from the top.

So you need to store the previous position of the bullet.

Depending on the 'quadrant' where lies that old position, then you can decide of the move you should do.

I did a small drawing to explain:

[image]

You see that if the bullet was previously in the 'horizontal corridor' (red in my drawing), then you know it's left or right: now just test if x was on left or right and you know.

Same goes for the 'vertical corridor' (blue).

Then, if the bullet was neither in those corridors, you have a corner collision, and four cases to handle.

Pseudo code:

```
 if ( bullet was previously in the red horizontal corridor)  {
     if ( was on the left )
          left collision
     else
          right collision
 } else if ( bullet was previously in the blue vertical corridor) {
     if ( up )
           up collision
     else
           down collision
 } else { // corner case
     // ... Test which of the 4 corner it was in
     if (was upper) {
           if (was left ) 
               up and left
           else
               up and right
     } else { // lower
           if (was left ) 
               down and left
           else
               down and right
     } 
 }
```

For instance, the first `if` writes:

```
if ( Math.abs(oldBulletY-enemyY) < enemiHeight/2 ) {
    if (oldBulletX < enemyX ) {
       // collision on the left
    } else {
       // collision on the right
    }
}
```

Notice that this is an approximation: in the diagonal hit case, the bullet might just as well have hit one or the other side, or both (corner). But this should work quite good.

If you want full precision, you'll have to go for a segment vs segment intersection: question becomes: which of the four segments of the enemy intersected the (oldBulletPosition, newBulletPosition) segment. And don't forget the corner cases.

Again I think the solution above should be good enough 95% of the time, especially since your bullets are slow.

Edit: I found a simpler solution, using 'real' quadrants, like in this drawing:

[image]

So depending on the quadrant (1,2,3,4), you know which is was hit with more accuracy. Sorry but no time now for the (boring) trigonometric stuff, let me know if you're interested (first solution might be good enough).

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed explanation, I've also had success with my above code.