# How to fix bad 2D collision

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, collision-detection, game-physics

I have a question regarding 2d physics in a JavaScript canvas game that I am working on. In my game I am using the following code to detect collision between a ball and a brick (rectangle). The collision code is working, but the ball passes through the object before it disappears, allowing the ball to clip through the brick field and destroy most of the bricks.

In conclusion, how can I make it so that the ball does not clip through the brick field?

Here is the code used for collision detection:

```
if(this.enabled && 
   ball.x + ball.vx < this.x + BRICK_WIDTH &&
   ball.x + ball.vx + ball.radius > this.x &&
   ball.y + ball.vy < this.y + BRICK_HEIGHT &&
   ball.y + ball.vy + ball.radius > this.y) {
    ball.vy = -ball.vy;
    this.enabled = false;
}
```

[Here is a video of the faulty collision detection](https://youtu.be/IrVa-KpgRnw)

[Also if you would like to, you can try it yourself](https://breakout-clone-benjamin6817.c9users.io/index.html)

Notice how the ball slightly passes through the blue bricks?

Comment: For fast moving objects (like your ball?), **you must find the initial collision point of the ball and the brick.** You can adapt this previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607871/how-to-create-obstacles-in-canvas/34624007#34624007) that shows how to collision test the leading edge of an object vs an obstacle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(this.enabled && 
   ball.x + ball.vx - ball.radius < this.x + BRICK_WIDTH &&
   ball.x + ball.vx + ball.radius > this.x &&
   ball.y + ball.vy - ball.radius < this.y + BRICK_HEIGHT &&
   ball.y + ball.vy + ball.radius > this.y) {
    ball.vy = -ball.vy;
    this.enabled = false;
}
```

You weren't incorporating the ball's radius in two of your distance calculations. I don't have the rest of your code, so you would have to verify if it works.

Comment: This fixed some of the problem, but the ball still clips through the brick field through the sides

Comment: @Ben What do you mean by the "sides"? Are you talking about the width of the rectangle?

Comment: Click on the link to try it out, and without moving the paddle, press space. The ball ends up taking out a big chunk of the bricks

Comment: @Ben You may need to implement some better collision detection then. Try finding the normal vector between the ball and the box, and then adjusting the ball's position with respect to the normal.

Comment: I have found that the problem no longer lies with the collision detection. Something else is wrong with the code, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the corners, during your check, you are adding the radius which is half the diameter. That means during a collision with the top the ball must go half way through the brick to meet the criteria.

try

```
     ball.y + ball.vy + ball.radius*2 > this.y
```

also in the other x check as well....