# Collision detection with rectangles

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

I have tried to make a small "game" with collision detection.

The problem is, in some cases objects just passes through. I am totally blind to the cause.

I have tried to create my own detection, which is commented out and then i tried this:

**[Code sample as fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywpkpkj4/)**

```
function rectanglesIntersect( minAx, minAy, maxAx, maxAy, minBx, minBy, maxBx, maxBy ) {
    var aLeftOfB = maxAx < minBx;
    var aRightOfB = minAx > maxBx;
    var aAboveB = minAy > maxBy;
    var aBelowB = maxAy < minBy;

    return !( aLeftOfB || aRightOfB || aAboveB || aBelowB );
}
```

Comment: If you want to have it moving slower, just change the FPS and you can easy add less items in the buttom of the example

Comment: Fast moving items may completely pass through the obstacle during one move -- that's called "tunneling". Here a previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607871/how-to-create-obstacles-in-canvas) showing how to find the initial collision point.

Comment: If you watch my demo they sometime collide while they are well inside each other?
And I make my checks before they move to next frame? So they should never colide?

Comment: Your `.update` allows rects to move 30px during one single move. With 2 rects that means they can move 60px per move relative to each other. That means it can easily intrude on (or fully pass through) another rect during a single move. You need to use math to determine the **initial collision point** between the 2 rects.

Comment: Can you give one more pointer what I am missing :)

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining how to test for collisions. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Luckily, your rects have these simplifying qualities when moving:**

- They only move in the Y direction (up or down).
- They all move at 30px per move.

**So you can determine if & where a rect pair will collide like this:**

1. At the **start of the move**, calculate if pair of rectangles can possibly  collide by testing if they are vertically aligned.

   ```
   rect1.x > rect2.x && rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width;
   ```
2. If the pair of rectangles is traveling towards each other, calculate if the pair is within 60 vertical pixels of each other. The 60 is important because each rect can travel 30 pixels per move so the rect pair can close in on each other by 30+30=60px per move.

   ```
   var willCollideThisMove = Math.abs(rect1.y-rect2.y)<=60;
   ```
3. If the pair will collide, then the pair will collide at the midpoint of their distance difference:

   ```
   var collisionY = Math.min(rect1.y,rect2.y)+Math.abs(rect1.y-rect2.y)/2;
   ```

Do these 3 calculations for all rect pairs.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :) Just what I needed to get going.